# Mixing Seam and GWT using the Seam Context-filter

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, seam2

I am trying to add a GWT page to an existing Seam2 application.  In the GWT page I am making use of GWT RPC to fetch data from the server.  I need to give that GWT servlet access to the Seam conversation context.  For this, I am attempting to use the context-filter discussed in section [29.1.4.8](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.0.CR1/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html#d0e22490) of the Seam2 user guide and making my GWT RPC servlet a Seam component.  The user guide specifies that the the filter requires that the Seam conversation id be set on the request sent to the servlet.  I am not sure how to do this with a RPC call, as it is made through a proxy and I don't think I have access to the request itself.  Is there any way to set a request parameter while using RPC or am I stuck building a request manually?  Also, does anyone have experience mixing GWT and Seam using the context-filter?  I am having trouble finding successful examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a filter to get access to the seam conversation context with GWT RPC. Have a look at the following link:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-seam/wiki/GettingStartedGWTRPC

Example (seam-gen application):
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-seam/source/browse/#svn/examples/HelloWorldSeamGen